# Constructing Points from native mouse events

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to get mouse zooming via mouse scroll working in Paper.js.

Paper.js doesn't have a [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event, so I need to construct a Paper.js [Point](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/) from the native `wheel` event, with correct coordinates, taking into account any [View](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/) transformations.

For example, this won't work:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const tool = new paper.Tool()

paper.setup(canvas)
paper.view.scale(2) // Zoom the view.

// This gives *wrong* coordinates, since we scaled/zoomed the view 
// and it's a native event that doesn't take into account PaperJS 
// view transformations.
canvas.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  const point = { x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY }
  console.log(point)
})

// This gives *correct* coordinates, since it's a PaperJS 
// event which takes into account the view transformations.
tool.onMouseUp = e => {
  console.log(e.point)
}
```

```css
canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-core.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
```

Comment: How is `toolZoomIn` defined?

Comment: @Evan I've asked this many years ago but IIRC `toolZoomIn` is a [`Tool`](http://paperjs.org/reference/tool/) with `zoomFactor` being a property on that Tool which specifies how much to zoom with each scroll.

Comment: I realize `toolZoomIn` is a Tool, but any chance you still have the code around for how you constructed it? This snippet and solution are not very useful without seeing how the tool worked.

Comment: @Evan Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native events won't have a `point` property, so we need to create a point value for it:

```
let point = paper.DomEvent.getPoint(e)
```

But since we want the point in relation to the canvas:

```
let point = paper.DomEvent.getOffset(e, canvas)
```

With this we can then convert to project space using [`view.viewToProject()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#viewtoproject-point):

```
point = paper.view.viewToProject(point)
```

Here's a working example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
const tool = new paper.Tool()

paper.setup(canvas)
paper.view.scale(2) // Zoom the view.

// This now gives *correct* points, taking into account
// the view transformations.
canvas.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
  const point = paper.view.viewToProject(paper.DomEvent.getOffset(e, canvas))
  console.log(point)
})

tool.onMouseUp = e => {
  console.log(e.point)
}
```

```css
canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.12.2/paper-core.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
```